# Level of Jackdaw

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I've played Assassin's Creed IV : Black Flag for a while, But I can't find any way to know level of Jackdaw?

Can any one please tell where I can find level of Jackdaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to view the Jackdaw's level. The only thing you can really do is pay attention to the color of the text when you look at another ship through the spyglass.

- Red: Tough Fight
- White: Evenly Matched
- Green: Easy Fight

Some people report that if you play a mission where you're in control of another ship and the Jackdaw is fighting with you, you can use the spyglass to look at the Jackdaw which will have a level, but I've never seen any confirmation if that's your actual level or just a fabricated number.

Comment: Actually, you can check the level of Jackdaw only ONCE using the spyglass in the mission in which you are with Bartholomev Roberts (The Sage) and you have to steal a level 70 Portuguese Man'O War ship. When you sail that ship, you can check the level of Jackdaw using the spyglass

Comment: Lies, there is a mission in which you must board blackbeard’s Queen anne’s Revenge and you can see the jackdaw through the spy glass

Answer (score 0):

In sequence 10, Black Bart's Gambit, aboard Nossa Senhor Man-o-war if you look at Jackdaw through spyglass you can see its level. If you've fully uprgaded the ship, it'll show level 45.